# onClick handler of react checkbox gives error

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

return method of my component has the following code segment:

```
              <List>
               {items.length > 0
                    &&items.map((item,index) => (
                      <List.Item>
                      <Checkbox> 
                      id={item.id}
                      onClick={handleCheckboxClick}                   
                      label={
                      <label> 
                      <PreferenceTag tagStyles={[styles.orange]}>
                      {item.name}
                      </PreferenceTag>
                      </label>
                             }
                      <Checkbox/>
                      </List.Item>
                    ))} 
               </List>
```

handleCheckBoxClick method is like this:

```
const handleCheckboxClick= async ()=> {
   var id=this.id;
    const result = await client.mutate({
      mutation:deleteIndustry,
      variables:{
        industryId:id
      }
    })

  }
```

mutation is:

```
const deleteIndustry=gql`
mutation deleteIndustry($industryId:String){
  deleteIndustry(industryId:$industryId)
}
`
```

When I click on a checkbox I get the following error:
**Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'value' of undefined**

Comment: Please format your question propery before asking

Comment: You should set your `id` into the `value` attribute of the `<checkbox />` and use that `value` instead of `this.id`

Comment: I tried it.But still the case is same

Comment: Where is your code which contains reading `value` property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify your handleCheckBoxClic as follows

```
const handleCheckboxClick= async ({currentTarget: input})=> {
   console.log(input);
   let id=input.id;
    const result = await client.mutate({
      mutation:deleteIndustry,
      variables:{
        industryId:id
      }
    })

  }
```

Hopefully it will work, BTW I have added the console for you to check the id/value/checked from the currentTarget/input

**Update**

Try `onChange={handleCheckboxClick}` instead of `onClick={handleCheckboxClick}`

I have used let instead of var `let id=input.id;`

@ShashiWDN you may try the following code to grab the checkbox id and checked/value

`//to get the ID
console.log(input.children[0].id);
//to get the value
console.log(input.children[0].checked);`

Comment: now I don't get an error.but when I console.log(id)  it gives nothing.and also mutation is not working. so the checked item is still remaining in the rendered list.any support is highly appreciated.

Comment: Using `console.log(input);` you will get the entire input and able to check which attributes are assigned to this input. Make sure you are using `onChange` in stead of `onClick`

Comment: I canged onClick to onChange.what I get is                                                    <div class="ui checked checkbox">                                                            
    <input class="hidden" id="a84ec563-258e-44fc-8b55-89568e3b9c72" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value=""><label for="a84ec563-258e-44fc-8b55-89568e3b9c72"><div class="container_yfxjz7-o_O-orange_el76y"><div class="text_vgdyss-o_O-text_yxnj9">Video</div></div></label></div>